# Mongodb - Update at multiple places in the same document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document something like this :

```
myDoc : {
    _id : a101
    name : John,
    batch : [{
        _id : batch101,
        value : physics
    },{
        _id : batch102,
        value : chemistry
    },{
        _id : batch103,
        value : maths
    }]
}
```

I want to update the "value" to "computers" where the batch._id is either "batch101" or "batch102" (not batch103).

Please help! Thanks in advance.

-Manish :)

Comment: can you please tell what you have tried to solve this

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot actually use the position operator or an atomic update to solve this problem because the positional operator only actually matches the FIRST found subdocument. Atm I believe this needs to be done client side and then sent back down to the database

Comment: As Sammaye notes, the easiest way to solve this might be to change the document in your client and then update with this modified document.

Comment: @Sammey and ACE : Thanks for your suggestions, can you please explain a bit how shall i do that in client side and send it back to the server side? Thanks.

Comment: Which client/driver are you using? http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/

Comment: I am using Node.js ( http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/#node-js )

Comment: I only can think of updating one part (batch101) once coming back and updating the second part in the second (batch102) db call. Can we not somehow do that in only one call?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments on the orignal question, the best solution here might be to work with the document on the client side.  I will break this down into a few steps:

1) Query for the document.  You mentioned you are working in node, so this will be represented in JSON.  Lets call this variable x

2) Go through your document finding the elements you want to update, this might look like:

```
for(i = 0; i < x.batch.length; i++) {  
    if(x.batch[i]._id == 'batch101') {  
        //do something
    }
}
```

(this code is not complete, obviously, but gives you an idea of what you want)

3) Now, using this changed document, update the old document in mongoDB.

This process should allow you to achieve your goal of updating certain elements in the batch list.